# In Rails, extended Integer class written in lib folder is not getting loaded with the eager loading of lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

I have created a file integer.rb in lib folder and that contains the following piece of code

```
class Integer
  def digits
    self.abs.to_s.size
  end
end
```

I am loading the lib folder in application.rb file with this line

```
config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

but it doesn't seem to be loading the lib/integer.rb file, but if I explicitly write
`require "#{config.root}/lib/integer"`
then the digits method I wrote gets available for the usage.
Why do I have to explicitly load the file when I am loading the whole lib folder already?

Rails version I use is 4.0.0

Comment: Maybe try adding another slash at the end like this:   
something/lib/

Comment: In `config/environments/development.rb`, do you by any change have the setting: `config.eager_load = false`? Make it `true`. Or, instead of `config.eager_load_paths`, use `config.autoload_paths`. (If my guess is true, I'll add it as an answer....)

Comment: Thanks Tom. It worked. But I have a doubt. When `config.eager_load = false` was present in `development.rb`, how come every other folder and file present in lib was getting loaded except integer.rb?

Comment: After looking into it more, I got to know something. When the condition `config.eager_load = false` is present in `development.rb` and `config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` is present in `application.rb` Rails loads the paths of the files present in the lib folder. when any class defined in lib is initialized, Rails checks the path and access the class. In my case lib/integer.rb path is loaded but when I called the method I wrote, it looked into the ruby's Integer class instead of looking into the lib/integer.rb file because of the `config.eager_load` condition.